# Preventing Data Truncation in AWS DMS: Preserving Accuracy of Large Values during Database Copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration, aws-dms

When using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to copy data between Postgres to S3, I'm encountering a problem where large values, such as '40654322183738962997233014465845312829', are getting truncated to '0.00' in the target database. This truncation is affecting the accuracy and integrity of the data. How can I address this issue and ensure that the copied data preserves its original value without any truncation?

The data type is numeric on Postgres side. I tried changing the datatype during transformation to numeric 40,0. As a result the values were not populating and it was just blank.